# Unstandardize Logistic Regression Coefficients

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, standardization, glmnet

Given design matrix X and vector of binary responses y, we can standardize X and fit a logistic regression and obtain "standardized" coefficients. How can I obtain the unstandardized coefficients? I know how to do it for linear regression, but not for logistic regression.

The reason I require this is that I am fitting a penalized logistic regression of sorts (my own algorithm, different from usual glmnet etc.).

Comment: It works exactly the same way for logistic regression as it does for linear regression.

Comment: Thanks. Another quick one- if the penalization forces some coefficients to zero, does that affect the calculations for the intercept?

Comment: The intercept can be considered just another coefficient (of a regressor whose values are constant), so unless the intercept is being treated in some special way by the penalization routine, one would expect it to be subject to change.